# Loop over records in SQL database; when a record matches a variable, then do something

Tags: python

I have a database with 3 records: AAA, BBB, CCC

I have a string variable = 'CCC'

What I want: if one of the records matches the string, then print 'I have a match'.

If there is no match in the records, print 'don't match', but I want it one time, so not for every value.

I have:

```
for i in records:
  if i == variable
  print('I have a match')
  else:
     print('don't match)
```

But now I get 2 times 'don't match' because AAA and BBB are a no match. I want 'don't match' just 1 time.

Comment: If you want only one "don't match" output, you have to move that out of the loop.

Comment: Just a note, don't loop over records in sql database. Use the query to filter what you desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
def match_string(records):
    for i in records:
        if i == 'CCC':
            return 'I have a match'
    return "don't match"

print(match_string(['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
shown = False
for i in records:
  if i == variable
  print('I have a match')
  else:
     if shown == False:
       print('don't match)
       shown = True
```